# How to backup and restore to have full record SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with

- record 1
- record 2
- record 3
  Then I delete
- record 1
- record 2
  Next, I add
- record 4
- record 5
- record 6
  How to backup and restore to have full record
- record 1
- record 2
- record 3
- record 4
- record 5
- record 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server backups won't solve this issue for you.

However you could use Temporal Tables.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15